# How to use the text color from the system wide GTK theme for SVG icons (GtkImage)?

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I want SVG icons displayed using GtkImage to change color based on the current GTK theme/text color. How can I achieve this without changing the SVG files themselves?

Glade preview with Materia-dark theme (icons should be white instad of black):
[image: black icons]

Glade preview with Yaru theme (icons should be dark grey instead of black):
[image: black icons]

main.py

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("window.glade")
window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()
```

window.glade:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
...
                 <object class="GtkAlignment">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="left_padding">16</property>
                    <property name="right_padding">16</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImage">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="pixbuf">gamepad-round-right.svg</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
...
  </object>
</interface>
```

The SVG icons are from https://materialdesignicons.com/ and look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M4,8H8V4A2,2 0 0,1 10,2H14A2,2 0 0,1 16,4V8H20A2,2 0 0,1 22,10V14A2,2 0 0,1 20,16H16V20A2,2 0 0,1 14,22H10A2,2 0 0,1 8,20V16H4A2,2 0 0,1 2,14V10A2,2 0 0,1 4,8M10,4V8H14V4H10Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer certainly comes far too late to help you, but I'm answering it anyway in case it will help others.

GTK+ does support recoloring symbolic icons, but it is very sparsely documented. In order to have *any* chance whatsoever of enabling any of it, **your icon's filename must literally end in `-symbolic`**, e.g. `gamepad-round-right-symbolic.svg`.

In my own code, I was loading the icons programmatically; in addition to renaming my icon file, I had to make sure I was using the `symbolic` version of the icon loading function, *and* I had to pass in the correct color manually. I don't know what the analogous thing to do in Glade is, but naming the file with `-symbolic` is a necessary first step.